# RODBC: able to connect to db but can't find table object

Tags: r, sqlite, rodbc

I am trying to connect `SQLite` database using `RODBC` in R. `RODBC` is able to connect to the database but is not able to get the list of tables in database using `sqlTables`, which returns `"0 rows"`. The database has 20 tables.

System: R 3.1.2, Windows 7, Rstudio

Code snippet

```
> library(RODBC)
> odbcGetInfo(bbdb1)
                                                          DBMS_Name 
                                                           "SQLite" 
                                                           DBMS_Ver 
                                                            "3.8.6" 
                                                    Driver_ODBC_Ver 
                                                            "03.00" 
                                                   Data_Source_Name 
                                                            "bbdb1" 
                                                        Driver_Name 
                                                  "sqlite3odbc.dll" 
                                                         Driver_Ver 
                                                            "0.999" 
                                                           ODBC_Ver 
                                                       "03.80.0000" 
                                                        Server_Name 
"C:\\Users\\shals\\Documents\\R in a nutshell\\nutshell\\data\\bb1" 
> sqlListTables(bbdb1)
Error: could not find function "sqlListTables"
> sqlTables(bbdb1)
[1] TABLE_CAT   TABLE_SCHEM TABLE_NAME  TABLE_TYPE  REMARKS    
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> sqlPrimaryKeys(bbdb1,func,errors=FALSE,as.is=TRUE,catalog=NULL,schema=NULL)
Error in sqlPrimaryKeys(bbdb1, func, errors = FALSE, as.is = TRUE, catalog = NULL,  : 
  object 'func' not found
```

Can anyone please help why sqlTables returning 0 rows when there are 20 tables in database.

Comment: bbdb1 <- odbcConnect(dsn="bbdb",believeNRows = FALSE,rows_at_time = 1) # changed the connection string as mentioned after which the code worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

changed the connection string as below after which the code worked fine.

```
bbdb1 <- odbcConnect(dsn="bbdb",believeNRows = FALSE,rows_at_time = 1)
```